# The Case Study Images are overlapping the Navbar, is there a way to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a site but the case study images are overlapping the navbar. I've tried fixing it but I can't seem to figure it out. I thought it was the CSS for the navbar but the navbar overlaps every other section except for these images.
Here's my fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/sgr0691/7gopqmq9/6/

```
   <section class="card-case">
    <h1 class="main-header">Case Studies</h1>
     <div class="wrap">
          <!-- First Case Study -->
          <div class="card" style="background-image:'http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3729/12516648584_d9bfc9f762_c.jpg';">
                    <header class="head">
                          <h3>
                        <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> <a href="main-blog.html">The Industry<span class="time">1hr ago</a></span></h3>
                    </header>
                    <article>
                          <a href="blog.html">
                          <h2 class="card-header">Exploring a snowy land where all is happy &amp; good.</h2></a>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut animal contentiones voluptatibus has. Cu wisi insolens vel, mei no tritani laoreet, ei his magna veritus sapientem. Eum harum noster ne, ne mei dicam placerat. Etiam solet lucilius per in./p>
                    </article>
                    <footer class="foot">
                            <img src="images/card-img-min.jpg" alt="" class="profile-pic" />
                            <span class="author"><a href="#">Brock Nunn</a></span>                               
                            <aside class="social">
                              <a class="fa fa-commenting-o" href="main-blog.html"></a>
                              <a class="fa fa-star-half-o"></a>
                            </aside>
                    </footer>  
          </div>
      <!-- Second Case Study -->
        <div class="card" style="background-image:'http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3729/12516648584_d9bfc9f762_c.jpg';">
                  <header class="head">
                    <h3>
                  <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i><a href="main-blog.html"> The Industry<span class="time">1hr ago</a></span></h3>
                  </header>
                  <article>
                    <a href="blog.html">
                    <h2 class="card-header">Exploring a snowy land where all is happy &amp; good.</h2></a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut animal contentiones voluptatibus has. Cu wisi insolens vel, mei no tritani laoreet, ei his magna veritus sapientem. Eum harum noster ne, ne mei dicam placerat. Etiam solet lucilius per in.</p>
                  </article>
                  <footer class="foot">
                    <img src="images/card-img-min.jpg" alt="" class="profile-pic" />
                    <span class="author"><a href="#">Brock Nunn</a></span>

                    <aside class="social">
                      <a class="fa fa-commenting-o" href="main-blog.html"></a>
                      <a class="fa fa-star-half-o"></a>
                    </aside>
                  </footer>
        </div>
    <!-- Third Case Study -->
        <div class="card" style="background-image:'http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3729/12516648584_d9bfc9f762_c.jpg';">            
                  <header class="head">
                    <h3>
                  <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> <a href="main-blog.html">The Industry<span class="time">1hr ago</a></span></h3>
                  </header>
                  <article>
                    <a href="blog.html">
                    <h2 class="card-header">Exploring a snowy land where all is happy &amp; good.</h2></a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut animal contentiones voluptatibus has. Cu wisi insolens vel, mei no tritani laoreet, ei his magna veritus sapientem. Eum harum noster ne, ne mei dicam placerat. Etiam solet lucilius per in.</p>
                  </article>
                  <footer class="foot">
                    <img src="images/card-img-min.jpg" alt="" class="profile-pic" />
                    <span class="author"><a href="#">Brock Nunn</a></span>                  
                    <aside class="social">
                      <a class="fa fa-commenting-o" href="main-blog.html"></a>
                      <a class="fa fa-star-half-o"></a>
                    </aside>
                  </footer>         
        </div>
        <!-- Fourth Case Study -->
        <div class="card" style="background-image:'http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3729/12516648584_d9bfc9f762_c.jpg';"s>
                  <header class="head">
                    <h3 class="top-header">
                  <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i><a href="main-blog.html"> The Industry<span class="time">1hr ago</a></span></h3>
                  </header>
                  <article>
                    <a href="blog.html">
                    <h2 class="card-header">Exploring a snowy land where all is happy &amp; good.</h2></a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut animal contentiones voluptatibus has. Cu wisi insolens vel, mei no tritani laoreet, ei his magna veritus sapientem. Eum harum noster ne, ne mei dicam placerat. Etiam solet lucilius per in.</p>
                  </article>
                  <footer class="foot">
                    <img src="images/card-img-min.jpg" alt="" class="profile-pic" />
                    <span class="author"><a href="#">Brock Nunn</a></span>

                    <aside class="social">
                      <a class="fa fa-commenting-o" href="main-blog.html"></a>
                      <a class="fa fa-star-half-o"></a>
                    </aside>
                  </footer>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not seeing any overlapping in your example

Answer (score 2):

You used twice `header` tag with same `z-index`, that is the reason why was overlapping:

```
header.head {
 z-index: 99;
}
```

Here is the fiddle updated: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7gopqmq9/24/)

Comment: Thank you Teuta for your help and the updated fiddle!

Comment: So basically assign it a different class name and add a div instead of using the header tag?

Comment: @sgr0691, you can add that class name, just use div insted of header. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.head{ 
  z-index:0;
 }
```

just apply z-index to your head class,  i tried it in your fiddle. Its working.

Comment: Would I apply it to the header or navbar class?

Comment: to your header tag, there is a css class called 'head', apply z-index to it

Comment: Changing the z-index to 0 didn't change it. Maybe I'm putting the 0 in the wrong class?

Comment: can i update your fiddle? so that you can clearly understand

Comment: I have updated your fiddle, check in the css section , where i have added the above css class. Thank me with an upvote